# Is there any way to get backup of running code of azure service

Tags: azure, cloud, backup

I want to take a backup of the code of cloud service that is running currently.Is there any way to take backup of current ?

Comment: Are you interested in getting a backup of the source code or the compiled code?

Comment: I want to get the backup as a package that was deployed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the backup of the package, do take a look at [`Get Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121.aspx) operation in Service Management API. This operation takes a backup of package and config file and stores in a blob container of your choice.

Comment: For just to download the current package, Which call I have to make please?

Comment: Can We also save the package at our local ?

Comment: So what you would do is first call this `Get Package` operation and when the operation completes these files will be stored as blobs. You can then simply download the blobs.

Comment: As First call: https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/package                              It also requires the deployment name but I dont know about the deployment name that is running

Comment: You could go with the 2nd option (deployment slot which would either be `Production` or `Staging`).

Comment: This will give me the history of all deployments and then I can see the deployment name, And then go to the first option to download the package by specifying the name of deployment>. Am I right please suggest?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `This will give me the history of all deployments and then I can see the deployment name`. Can you please explain?

Comment: Is this necessary to give deployment name for download the package? As I dont know about the deployment  name

Comment: Like I said, you would know the deployment slot (there are 2 choices really) so you can specify the deployment slot and get the package running in that slot. Once the package is copied to blob storage, you can download the package (no need for the deployment name). HTH.

Comment: Thanks very much, I am trying

Comment: I have tried but I am always getting this error     "The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription."    I have same certificates installed on my machine as well as azure portal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48576/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-kulbir-singh)

Comment: @Gourav one thing please Is Get Package also works for web deploy. Means if deployments are done using web deploy not via package upload.  It will download the current running package or the package that was ever uploaded ? may be after one deployment throughpackage upload others are done via web deploy.. Please suggest

Comment: AFAIK, Get Package will fetch the currently running package. I'm not sure about web deploy but how would you deploy your code through web deploy in a cloud service?

Comment: I have one problem please. I have deployed my code on azure   I have make my package and on portal I have choosed "update production deployment". Everything is fine after deployment except IP of cloud service is changed. Could you please help me to sort it out why it happen and any solution to escape it from in future